# htaccess 301 Redirect Cpanel to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a site at mysite.com with blog entries in the form of:

`mysite.com/year/month/title.html`

I want to redirect all these blogs to

`wordpress_site.com/year/month/title/`

I have added this to my .htaccess file in my public_html folder through Cpanel:

`## 301 Redirect Entire Directory
RedirectMatch 301 mysite.com(.*) wordpress_site.com/$1`

But the redirect does not seem to be working - what am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hostname isn't part of what gets matched by the regex, try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)\.html$ http://wordpress_site.com/$1/$2/$3/
```